# Partitioning During Installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

[image]

I'm a windows user and I wanna install ubuntu.

I have a lot of questions about installation and I don't know much about it. I'll be happy if you answer me.

1- If I choose 'Something Else ', does it install ubuntu alongside windows? (I just wanna have one OS on my laptop)

2- How should I keep my data during installation ?

3- If I choose 'Replace windows with ubuntu', which partitions will be created?

Thanks ... :)

Comment: Install ubuntu alongside will alter the disk free space and install ubuntu alongside of windows. In the option 2 it will replace windows with ubuntu. The something else option is for the expert, who want to tailor make the disk partition based on the need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. The easiest and safest way is making a backup in an external drive.
3. An EFI partition (if your machine is UEFI) and a system partition:

[image]

Comment: if i  create a backup of my data , after installation , how can i send them to my computer and in which partition they will be stored ?

Comment: EFI partition is for booting, you don't access it at all. You have then one partition left to place your data, which you should acomodate in your `/home/youruser/somedirs` folder. More complicated ways include creating another partition to store data, but you have to be up to the task, meaning that you have to know how to create partitions, and when installing know how to manage the "Something else" option.

Comment: To put your data back to your hard drive, you have to plug your external drive and it will automount. Then just copy/paste.

Comment: You can make the backup from the usb installer.